# divs distributed unequally in grid layout

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, grid-layout

I have a grid in bootstrap like the below one. It works well for large screens. But when it comes to medium screens it is not stacking up well.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
    p{
        padding: 50px;
        font-size: 32px;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: center;
        background: #f2f2f2;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-12"><p>Box 1</p></div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-12"><p>Box 2</p></div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-12"><p>Box 3</p></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-12"><p>Box 4</p></div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-12"><p>Box 5</p></div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-12"><p>Box 6</p></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have to maintain two row classes and I cannot go for col-md-4. Is it possible anyway? The problem I get when I go for col-md-4 is the divs are getting overlapped(not with the above code, But in actual case.)

Comment: if it works for large screen, so you just apply the same style for medium and small screens. <div class="col-sm-4"> this will apply col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 by default.

Comment: I cannot apply col-md-4. It has to be two coloumns for medium screen.

Answer (score 0):

When using bootstrap grids you always want the `col-` to add up to 12 in one row.

```css
 p {
     padding: 50px;
     font-size: 32px;
     font-weight: bold;
     text-align: center;
     background: #f2f2f2;
 }
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
                <p>Box 1</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
                <p>Box 2</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
                <p>Box 3</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
                <p>Box 4</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
                <p>Box 5</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
                <p>Box 6</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

[Check out this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ja9johb9/2/) to see the way this grid responds to resolution change.

Hope this helps.

EDIT: Here is a link to [Bootstrap Grid Templates](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/). Its a great resource to always go back to until you memorize it.

Comment: by the way, there are no classes like col-*-0 in the bootstrap, so no need to apply them

Comment: Is it by any chance possible to make it 2-2-2 for medium screens. By media queries or any thing?